# Screen Mask based on cursor position on page using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseevent

I am trying to add an overlay to the screen then depending on where the cursor is in the document window there will be a transparent area where you can see the website below but everything else is masked out.

I realised I would have to do this with 2 divs. 1 Div for the top half of the screen then a bottom div for the bottom half of the screen.

[image: masked screen layout]

As you can see in the image, the blue areas are the top and bottom divs that mask out the website leaving the gap in the middle to see the website below.

I an trying to get the 2 divs to change their heights depending on cursor position on the screen so i can sort of move the viewing pane up and down the screen.

I have tried to tie into the pageY event and change the height of the top div like so:

```
$( document ).mousemove(function( event ) { 
        var h = event.pageY;
        $('#topDiv').css({"height":h}); 


    });
```

This sort of achieves a desired effect but it only chnages the height when the cursor touches the top div.

I tried to add the same function to the bottom div also but it creates a weird mirrored effect like they are working in opposites.

I need to get it so the top div and bottom div stay around 40px away from the cursor at all times when moving it up and down the screen.

I cant figure out how to offset the space required and also to make both divs work in harmony and not in opposite.

http://jsfiddle.net/j2cwqsxk/4/

Comment: Did you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/j2cwqsxk/7

Comment: You are amazing! That is fantastic! thank you fo your kind help! that is almost exactly what I want to achieve! I added the variables outside the mousemove function and it did not work, then moved them inside and it worked perfect! - Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost solved the problem yourself, only the bottom div did not respond as wanted.

The bottom div has to get smaller when the cursor moves down and it has to be the full height of the window when the cursor is at the top. To do this we need to know the height of the window. I took a bit of Javascript code that seems to do this well and then I computed the height of the bottom div as `pageHeight-h-40`:

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var pageHeight = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                           html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );


$( document ).mousemove(function( event ) { 
            var h = event.pageY;
            $('#rwMaskTop').css({"height":h-40}); 
            $('#rwMaskBottom').css({"height":pageHeight-h-40});     
        });
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/j2cwqsxk/7

Comment: Thank you for your kind and concise answer. This has solved the problem exactly as I hoped to achieve. Thank you KIKO

Answer (score 1):

This creates the same effect using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) and [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). It uses a pseudo-element (`::before`) on the body, and it manipulates it's top and bottom borders.

**Note:** not supported by IE.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', ({ pageY: h }) =>
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--border-pos', `${h}px`)
);
```

```css
:root {
  --border-size: 40px;
  --border-pos: 0px;
}

body::before {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(0, 116, 217, 0.5);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: calc(var(--border-pos) - var(--border-size)) 0 calc(100vh - var(--border-pos) - var(--border-size)) 0;
  content: '';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ori, Your solution was very interesting to see how this effect is achieved in a complete different way. Your suggestion works perfectly. I need this too work in all browsers, but thank you very much for kindly taking the time to support me